# Octave for windows quit if I type any undefined command

Tags: octave

I install octave on Windows and Linux. If I type any wrong command in prompt, Octave for Linux will show error message `error: 'typo' undefined near line 1 column 1` but still keep in octave environment. However, **octave for Windows** will show error message and immidietely **quit to cmd**, I have to launch octave again.

How to set octave for Windows so that it keep in if any typo in octave environment?

Comment: The usual questions: What version of Octave, which build? Have you used the MXE Installer/Cygwin/foobar? Which Windoze version? Are you using the GUI or the CLI? As you say "quit to cmd" I'm guessing you are running the CLI on Windoze?